# Mongodb Aggregation: Merge array of objets into one

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given a document like that:

```js
results: [
{
  name: 'vitor',
  age: 40,
  colors: [ 'black', 'white', 'blue' ]
},
{
  name: 'vinicius',
  age: 32,
  colors: [ 'green', 'orange', 'blue' ]
},
{
  name: 'pedro',
  age: 17,
  colors: [ 'purple' ]
},
]
```

what is the best way to merge this array into a single object grouping every property into an array like that:

```js
{
  name: ['vitor', 'vinicius', 'pedro'],
  age: [40, 32, 17],
  colors: [ 'black', 'white', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple' ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$colors",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "name": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT.name"
      },
      "age": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT.age"
      },
      "colors": {
        "$addToSet": "$$ROOT.colors"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oN2v60ODOHI)

Comment: This preserves duplicates on the colors array ehich i didnt want to but overall answers the question so thank you!